# Filter data in DataTable: multiple queries vs DataView

Tags: performance, google-visualization

I'm working with Google charts, in this case the Google ColumnChart.
My project is to get the data from the database and to put it into a [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).
After the data has been loaded into the [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), the data can be filtered.

For example:
The user wants the data to be from 2012 only instead of from 2010 until 2013.

Now I've got two choices:

1. Do one database query to get all of the data and filter it by using a DataView. With this DataView, it's possible to show a piece of the DataTable. So, everytime the user changes the filter options, a new DataView will be made based on the filter options.
2. Execute a new database query every time the user changes the filter options. A new DataTable can be created with the results.

The query in choice one will return about 2000 rows, each with about 20 values, and there are about 50 users requesting the page at the same time. There are about 50 filter options available.

Which choice has the best performance?

If choice one is the best, what about memory usage?

In short, what's the best option?

If there are any other options available, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if there's a proper way to answer this. Once the data and script are loaded client-side, save for geocharts everything gets rendered locally. So it's a matter of how quick the computers are, and how quick your server for the query is. I'd wager that it'd be better to do it client-side.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I'm looking for some arguments to do the one or the other. There are a lot of queries already done by other pages so maybe it's faster to do it client-side. But at the other hand the client could have a slow connection which causes the page to have a high loading time. If anyone else has an answer/opinion or maybe a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: 40,000 values isn't really that much at all to get at once. Even over a slow connection, just downloading text, and assuming 10 bytes per value, you're still only talking 400k or so (and I think 10 bytes per value is a lot if it's mostly numbers). If you're that worried about response time, you can have two queries -- one for the initial data that populates the chart, and then a second query that runs after the chart is ready that downloads the rest of the data.

Comment: But when 50 users are requesting the chart in one second than it will be about 2000000 values at once. Then we are talking about 20 MB's of data requested from the database by 50 queries. Besides this I like the idea of two queries. The user has a fast response and the rest will be downloaded in the background. Thank you for that. Are there any other possibilities? Are there any arguments for using a new small query for every filter option?

Comment: The question is whether you will suffer more from frequent small queries, or from sending a load of data all at once but not have to do lots of different queries. And that's probably getting in to a slightly different topic (or at least one I can't handle). You may want to ask to SuperUser or somesuch where they know more than me.

Comment: We've made the descision to use multiple queries because in the beginning the users will try every filter options and that will cause a high query amount of the database, but after a while they will watch the graph once a month or week. The database is capable to handle that amount of requests. Maybe if the user amount will increase rapidly in the future, it might the best way to use a dataview. Thank you, jmac for all the ideas and support.

Comment: No problem. Whatever you decide going with, it'd be appreciated if you answered your own question and let us know the pluses and drawbacks of what you chose for future generations!

Comment: I will do that when I'm ready